# how to use css Transition on displaying block when doing hover on different block?

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<div class="onediv"><a href="">text</a></div>
<div class="nextdiv">
 <p>testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testingtesting.
 </p>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nextdiv{display: none;}
```

JQUERY

```
$( ".onediv a" ).hover(function() {
 $('.nextdiv').css({'display' : 'block'});
});

$( ".onediv a" ).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.nextdiv').css({'display':'none'});
});
```

When I hover to text then .nextdiv will display. Now I want to apply transition when that .nextdiv will display. 
thankyou in advance.

Comment: Try .hide() and .show() functions

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".onediv").hover(function() {
  $(this).next('.nextdiv').toggle('slow')
});
```

```css
.nextdiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onediv"><a href="">text</a>
</div>
<div class="nextdiv">
  <p>testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testingtesting.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="onediv"><a href="">text1</a>
</div>
<div class="nextdiv">
  <p>text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="onediv"><a href="">text2</a>
</div>
<div class="nextdiv">
  <p>text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2.
  </p>
</div>
```

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

1. You can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
2. Move the hover to div not a

Comment: Add a delay in your toggle, to realize there's a transition and not just a display. :-)

Comment: @Alexis hope adding 'slow' is enough :)

Comment: Yeah, perfect ! :D

Comment: thanks for your ans but my question is how to use transition? when hover it should take some time to display. this is what I am asking. can you plz help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display:none`, you can use other techniques to hide the element like applying a negative `z-index` so that the transition takes effect when displayed:

```js
$(".onediv a").hover(function() {
  $('.nextdiv').addClass('show');
}, function() {
  $('.nextdiv').removeClass('show');
});
```

```css
.nextdiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -999;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.show {
  position: static;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onediv"><a href="">text</a>
</div>
<div class="nextdiv">
  <p>testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testingtesting.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what exactly what I want at that time.